# Printing characters from a string occurring in another string

Tags: java, string

I want characters from a string occurring in another string to be printed; characters which don't occur replaced by an asterisk.

For example:

```
string 1: helloworld
string 2: hord
```

Output should be:

```
h***o**r*d
```

Only characters from string 2 which occur in string 1 ar printed; characters from string 1 which don't occur in string 2 are represented as an asterisk.

I have written the following code:

```
public class ProgramonStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        String str1 = "helloworld";
        String str2 = "hord";
        StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sbf2 = new StringBuffer();
        String output;
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
                if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                    sbf.append(str1.charAt(i));
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                sbf.append('*');
            }
        }
        output = sbf.toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
            int count = 0;
            if (output.charAt(i) != '*') {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < output.length(); j++) {
                    if (output.charAt(j) == output.charAt(i)) {
                        //output.replace(output.charAt(j), '*');
                        sbf2.append('*');
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                sbf2.append(output.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sbf2);
        System.out.println(sbf2);
    }    
}
```

Since then I am getting output as:`h*****or*d`

So can anyone correct my program to get the appropriate output i.e.,:`h***o**r*d`

Comment: at least fix your indentation

Comment: `output` contains the string you want. Why the second loops?

Comment: You don't provide enough information about your problem. How do you expect to use the two `String`s to produce the third one?

Comment: @Eypros I have mentioned that the two input strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code similar to this which gives the required output

```
public class ProgramOnStrings {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Compare cobj=new Compare();
    cobj.compareStrings();
}

}

class Compare
{
String s1="helloworld";
String s2="hord";
int array[];
String small,big;

Compare()
{
    if(s1.length()<s2.length())
      {

          small=s1;
          big=s2;
          array=new int[small.length()];

      }
      else
      {
        small=s2;
        big=s1;
        array=new int[s2.length()];  

      }
    System.out.println("small\t"+small+"\tbig\t"+big);
}

public void compareStrings()
{
    int j=0;
   for(int i=0;i<big.length();i++)
  {

      if(small.charAt(j)==big.charAt(i))
      {
         array[j]=i;
         System.out.println("if: The selected positions are"+i);
        j++;  
      }


  }

  int m=0;
  for(int k=0;k<big.length();k++)
  {
      if(array[m]==k)
      {
          System.out.print(small.charAt(m));
          m++;
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.print("*");
      }
 }
}

}
```

Comment: Nice to hear a reply from you friend. if you had any questions in future plz do post in this site

Answer (score 2):

You only need to iterate once over the text string. Iterate over it and compare the current character in the string with the next character in the second string. If it's equal, then consume the character from the second string, that is, increment the `pointer`. Else print an asterisk character (`*`).

If `pointer < str2.length()` is not `true`, that means that all characters from the second string are consumed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "helloworld";
    String str2 = "hord";
    int pointer = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        if (pointer < str2.length() && str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(pointer)) {
            sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
            pointer++;
        }
        else {
            sb.append('*');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

*Notice that it is better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.*